# How to generate a unique value for particular field in java and store it as a constant

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

Run time generate a  particular unique id for particular field like for bank -1234 it should represent only unique value every time.

I have used generate_guid() but in second run it changes the value.

Is there any solution.Thanks in advance.
Your valuable response will be appreciated.

Comment: If you need to persist the value, store it in a database or serialize the object. "Random" refers to a value which is supposed to change on each execution.

Comment: I have to generate the values and need to set the values in some Fields in the same program. Handle only at the run time.

Comment: Do you have any code that you can share? Would using a deterministic hash help? What kind of data are you oping to generate a unique id for? How much data are you hoping to generate this id for?

Comment: yes, can you please be a little bit more specific of what you have and what you'd love to have? Maybe share the code you have so far?

Comment: This is the use case that generate the unique key for specific fields value. The run time approach is because whenever new unique data added it  generate the unique key for that. This is like you have a name and you have assigned one unique adhar number that will only represent you.

Comment: Can you share your code and some sample data or output? If you want to store a unique value for a unique id/field, you could use a dictionary to store your key value pair. Although, I need more information to further investigate the best option.